# UMat is slow (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, cpu, image-resizing

I've been Tinkering around with OpenCV to resize a huge batch (100k+) of Images (16-24MP). And somehow it seems that using the CPU is always around 30-50% faster. 
As I am Running a ryzen 1700x and an 1080ti I was expecting it to be the other way round.
It would be nice if someone could give me a hint on what I am doing wrong.
I am running OpenCV 4.0.0.pre and OpenCL 1.2

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
path =''
dic=[]
def resizer(file):
    img = cv.imread(file)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]

    dim = float(width)/float(height)
    if dim > 1:
        width=4000
        height= 4000/dim
        start_time = time.time()
        res = cv.resize(cv.UMat(img), (int(width), int(height)), interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    else:
        width=4000*dim
        height= 4000
        start_time = time.time()
        res = cv.resize(cv.UMat(img), (int(width), int(height)), interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    name=file.split('/')[-1]
    cv.imwrite('/small/{}'.format(name), res)

for file in glob.glob(path+'*.JPG'):
    dic.append(file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool=Pool(16)
    pool.map(resizer, dic)
    pool.terminate()
```

Comment: I suspect you are using the wrong tool. IMHO, OpenCV is better suited to *"computer vision"* tasks. I would suggest you consider `vips` or its Python bindings for post-processing or resizing.

Comment: "I am running OpenCV 4.0.0.pre" -- that looks like an unstable development build from the master branch - this may be in some turmoil right now as work progresses on the new major version. Unless you're working on the OpenCV code itself, you might be better off using a stable version (built from a tag, e.g. 3.4.1).

Comment: We also tested it one 3.4.0, with the same results.

Comment: @evilblubb Yeah, I kinda expected that, but felt it was important to mention. I noticed similar behaviour in `cvtColor`, when I was recently playing with implementing a new conversion option. I tried comparing the existing implementations I was taking inspiration from, and the OpenCL variants weren't any faster than the parallelized CPU based impls. I'll have to dig into it further to figure out what's happening... so far it's quite puzzling, I've had the same expectations as you had (and I discounted the overhead of transferring to/from GPU memory, AFAICT)

Comment: @evilblubb You might want to try and enable [tracing](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Profiling-OpenCV-Applications) (see the second half of that page) and see what functions are being called there to get some insight into what is happening. Or try doing some profiling to see where it spends the most time.

Comment: I'll have a look, had a busy weekend, so it might take me a day or two

Answer (score 4):

For computationally simple tasks like a resize it takes longer to ship the data to the GPU memory and back again than you save by the faster computation.

Especially since openCV will be doping the resize with parallel CPU cores and long instruction word SIMD optomised assembler on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The GPU has high processing power, so it means it performs calculations much faster than the CPU, but when you perform a lot of assignment operations in your code, it is not the best option, since the GPU's memory power is lower than CPU. This is why there is more efficiency when you run your code snippet through the CPU, in which the predominance of operations are assignments.